# Поиск SearchView, можно ли задать действие если отменить ввод текста?

Tags: java, android, поиск, searchview

Сам код:

```
// поиск
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        // Действия после нажатия ввод
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {

            return false;
        }

        // Действия после каждого нажатия
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
            mAdapter.filter(text);
            return false;

        }
    });
```

С вводом текста все понятно, но нужно, чтобы сработало определенное действие если отменить ввод. Есть ли такая возможность??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее при очистке ввода вызовется колбэк изменения ввода и строка там будет пуста.

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) 
    { System.out.println("QUERY CLEARED"); } 
    else 
    { mAdapter.filter(text); }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Я уже примерно так и сделал